# OpenID token from Google (using www)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid

I've come across the following situation when using OpenID and Google as the authenticator.

If you type siteName.com it takes you to http://sitename.com

Which returns a different token than if I were to login to www.siteName.com, which would take me to http://www.siteName.com

As a result, Google returns a different authentication token.  Is there a simple fix around this? Maybe redirect the user from siteName.com to www.siteName.com?  Would this be a server issue, or is this something I can do programmatically?

Thanks in advance for any answers, this question had plagued me for some time now as I just figured out why others had been receiving different credentials upon logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Google is keying off of is the `realm` (and/or `return_to`, but probably just `realm`) in your OpenID request.  So if you change your code to use consistent values there, and Google sends users back to a consistent domain on the `return_to`, your users will have consistent identifiers.